# Does `ORDER BY` work with aggregate functions?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

need to select top students from college by average mark on a subject. (there are 2 tables: students: `id, name`, subjects: `id, name`, marks: : `id, student_id, subject_id, val`)

The query I made:

```
select s.id, sb.id, avg(m.val) as avgmark
from marks m
join students s on s.id = m.student_id
join subjects sb on sb.id = m.subject_id
where sb.name = 'math' and avgmark > 80
GROUP BY student_id, subject_id
ORDER BY avgmark DESC
```

doesn't work AFAIK because of aggregate functions work after `where` clause works.

What is the reasonable way to perfom it?
Do I need to use `having` somehow?
Does `ORDER BY` work with aggregate functions?

Comment: Are you telling us it actually does not work (you get an error?) or you just think it won't work (so why not test it?)

Comment: You should always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS, so as to get answers valid for that DBMS.

Comment: The WHERE clause is evaluated _before_ the SELECT list. This means the column alias hasn't been created yet when you try to use it in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not about `ORDER BY`. You aggregate the joined rows in order to end up with one row per student and subject ID. `WHERE` happens before aggregation. In `WHERE` we look at the original rows, not at aggregation results. If you want to look at an aggregation result like the average, then you must place the condition in the `HAVING` clause instead.

This query gets you all students with an average grade over 80, showing the top students first:

```
select m.student_id, m.subject_id, avg(m.val) as avgmark
from marks m
join students s on s.id = m.student_id
join subjects sb on sb.id = m.subject_id
where sb.name = 'math'
group by m.student_id, m.subject_id
having avg(m.val) > 80
order by avgmark desc;
```

The students table is superflouous by the way and the subjetcs table only needed for a lookup, so I'd write:

```
select m.student_id, m.subject_id, avg(m.val) as avgmark
from marks m
where m.subject_id = (select sb.id from subjects sb where sb.name = 'math')
group by m.student_id, m.subject_id
having avg(m.val) > 80
order by avgmark desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works, but not all databases allow use of column aliases to reference the column within the same query.

For a universally portable solution, either repeat the expression:

```
ORDER BY avg(m.val) DESC
```

Or refer to the column by number:

```
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know a database that does not support aliases in the `order by` clause?